# python mock.mock_reset() returns mock instead of resetting the mock

Tags: python, mocking

While using the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library, I've encountered a situation where calling `my_mock.reset_mock()` method returns a new `Mock` instance instead of resetting the `my_mock`. Apparently I'm somehow masking `Mock.reset_mock()`, but I cannot figure out how this happened.

Sample run (Python 2.7):

```
>>> mocks.normal_mock.mock_calls
Out[6]: []
>>> mocks.normal_mock.reset_mock()
>>> mocks.normal_mock.mock_calls
Out[8]: []
>>> mocks.abnormal_mock.mock_calls
Out[2]: []
>>> mocks.abnormal_mock.reset_mock()
>>> <MagicMock name='abnormal_mock.reset_mock()' id='157604104'>
>>> mocks.abnormal_mock.mock_calls
Out[4]: [call.reset_mock()]
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Additional info:

- All mocks are encapsulated in a designated class, which is instantiated once, and reset between test in `unittest.TestCase.tearDown()`.
- All mocks are created calling `patch.start()` on some patched object/method/module
- Both normal and abnormal mocks in my example mock-out a module imported by the UUT (a different module each)

Comment: Where are `mocks.normal_mock` and `mocks.abnormal_mock` coming from? Can you show the code that produces them? (Also, if `reset_mock()` were returning a new mock, there would be output showing the return value.)

Comment: @user2357112 - showing all of the code would be overwhelming. I've added some more info re how mocks are created - I hope will suffice.

Comment: Did you actually try this in an interpreter? The output format looks like you typed in what you think would happen if the problem matched your mental model; there's at least one part that doesn't look like actual interpreter output. Make sure you actually test things, or you'll miss opportunities to solve your problem or narrow down the cause.

Comment: @user2357112 - yes, this is an actual output from a PyCharm interactive console. I've changed the names of the mocks for brevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue.

Due to some convoluted way of mock creation, I was calling `patch()` on an already patched module, namely, I was patching a `Mock()` object. Since `autospec` was `True` for the patch call, `mock_reset()` was  patched.

The solution was to simplify mock creation flow.